# Enabling CI profiler gives json parse error

Tags: codeigniter

I have CI profiler on like so:
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE)
in my controller.

This is giving JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character error. When I turn the profiler off its ok.

I find that ajax response text has the profiler info as well.

Could someone enlighten on me this.
How can I turn the profiler on in CI and avoid jason parse error. 
thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it like this in my core controller class (extends CI_Controller and is the parent class of all my app controllers):

```
if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
    $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
}
```

You could also put:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE);
```

In your ajax controller method so THAT method doesn't include the profiler data/string.

Comment: not as long as that line of code exists there...but you dont' WANT it in Ajax requests that are returning JSON.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yes, i'm aware that this question is +4 years old, but from 2013 to 2017 Ajax Calls got much more popular on our websites/web systems and not having some feedback on server-side performance was not an option for me, so here's what I've done:

application\core\MY_Controller.php: (Load profiler as Library)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if(ENVIRONMENT === 'development'){
            $this->load->library('profiler'); //(don't use: $this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE), use it as a library!)
        }
    }
}
```

WHERE and WHEN you need it get the output just as: (Remember to extend MY_Controller instead of CI_Controller)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Somecontroller extends MY_Controller {

    function ajaxCall()
    {
        // Do some stuff
        $ret = array(
            'something' => 'yada yada yada',
            '_profiler' => $this->profiler->run()
            );
        header("Content-type:application/json");
        return print(json_encode($ret));
    }

}
```

Now within your Javascript append the profiler output without breaking your JSON structure:

```
<script>
    var ajaxReturn; // Your prefered ajax call (native JS or jQuery or wathever)
    if ( typeof ajaxReturn === 'string') {
        ajaxReturn = JSON.parse(ajaxReturn);
    }
    //-- Do some stuff
    //-- Append the profiler output
    document.getElementByTagName('body')[0].append(ajaxReturn._profiler); //-- or jQuery: $('body').append(ajaxReturn._profiler);
</script>
```

Final notes:

Of course this aproach will polute your ajax call with an extensive HTML for the profiler, so NEVER leave this profiler active in PRODUCTION, and even on DEVELOPMENT just use it WHEN you're actually profiling your application otherwise you're probably better without it.

Hope it helps someone else as it was usefull to me.